# Composing emails with 11pt or 12pt font size?

Tags: gmail, font

Is it possible to compose an email in Gmail with an 11pt or 12pt font size?
(In a way that the recipient also sees the font size difference.)

As of Feb 2015, the only options available are:

- Normal (around 10pt)
- Large (around 13.5pt)
- Huge (around 24pt)

[image: Gmail font size: small, normal, large, huge]

Would love to know if someone is aware of a plugin, browser extension or workaround to enable this?

Comment: The gap between 10pt and 13.5pt is so large.. Wish I could use 12pt or 11pt

Comment: The gap between 13.5 and 24 is insane. Literally all the useful sizes lie in that missing gap.

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't allow you to write emails in HTML. You can either use the Outlook website to compose the email and forward it your Gmail account and copy-paste the rich text of this message in other messages.

Alternatively, you can use the [ctrlq.org/html-mail](http://ctrlq.org/html-mail/) - it uses the Gmail API to send HTML mails from your Gmail account.

Comment: Yeah, the only way I've been able to is to copy+paste content from a Google Doc where you have more control over the font size. Pity this isn't possible directly in Gmail.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your email on a Google Doc and format as you like. Once done, paste your content into your mail body from there along

Answer (score 1):

I followed [this Google community answer](https://support.google.com/mail/thread/39328745?hl=en&msgid=39330258) based on [this blog post](https://blogs-on-gmail.blogspot.com/2019/05/canned-responses.html#CR1) to use a 12 point font as suggested by badou-mr and Aveeral Jain.

I first made a document in Google Docs with Arial 12pt as the font for the text and added a few lines of text in 12 pt Arial like so:

```
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
```

Use as many lines as you want to give you space to write your emails.

Then as mentioned in the answer in the Google Community answer, enable templates.
Create a new blank draft email.
Copy paste the lines in Arial 12pt from your Google Doc (aaaaa above) into this draft and use the triple dot menu to find the "Save draft as template" -> "Save new template" and name it something you find easy, e.g. "default" or "Arial12pt" or "default12pt"

Now you can use this template in every email.

Of course, this is a workaround and not a solution. But for the moment this is the closest you get without installing any extension or using a full fledged email client on top of gmail.

- You have to delete the a's in every new email
- You have to keep one junk 12pt draft open, so as to copy the 12pt formatting into emails which are replies or forwards to the emails of others.

Answer (score -1):

Use a template in gmail.
First, copy past the font with the right si that you want (e.g., outlook) into gmail

Comment: How do you suggest making a reusable template in Gmail?